# SQL: Does the BY keyword do anything beyond enhance readability?

Tags: sql

In other words, are there any scenarios in which GROUP or ORDER are used without being immediately followed with BY?

Comment: Nope, such is the syntax. You can think of `GROUP BY` as one keyword, not two.

Comment: If any RDMBS accepts that shorthand, it's not ANSI-compliant and won't work in most if not all other RDBMSs so not sure why you would ever use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't add any value to the site. Reading the documentation should satisfy that curiosity.

Comment: Yup, upon reflection, I can't say that you don't have a point Daniel. I will place the vote of death to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it may have a historical reason, the creators of the original `SQL` wanted it(`SQL`'s syntax) to be more similar to English instead of a programming language(like `C`).

So, I guess again it's safe to think as `GROUP BY` as if it's `group_by` in `C`(assuming `C` has some `group_by` routine), Same for `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, the keywords are stated as;
`ORDER BY`, and not `ORDER`, and so goes it for `GROUP`. It's only identified as `GROUP BY` in its syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true.... I just created a table Order with a columns Group and By. I was unable to query the table nor from either column without wrapping the names in brackets.

Comment: That's because of those being 'ODBC Reserved Keywords' in SQL, see more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql